# How to synchronize animation of contentOffset change and hiding/showing keyboard?

Tags: ios, uitableview, synchronization, core-animation

How to synchronize ***hidind/showing*** keyboard animation with `tableView.contentOffset` animation?
In my program when I tap to cell of `tableView`, this `tableView.contentOffset` changes and cell's `textField` becomes first responder. I try to synchronize animation of this actions, but no result.

**UPDATE**

I fond solution:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
         animations:^{[textView becomeFirstResponder];
                      tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 100.0f);}
         completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

But still there is one problem: When I call this method first time, keyboard apears from position not buttom like usual. When call this method second time, all right. How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using auto layout in your project. Suppose you have applied top, right, bottom and left constraint to UITableView and when keyboard going up you just need to update the bottom constraint to keyboard height and that time sdk UITextField will automatically scroll to the position from where it can visible on UITableView, for this you don't need to set content offset.

You can add notification for "UIKeyboardWillShowNotification" so before showing keyobard UITableView height will get decrease by updating bottom constraint and then control will go on UItextField so this will visible automatically.